# How can I have atos print mangled names?

Tags: ios, debug-symbols, name-mangling

I'm running `atos` to symbolicate addresses using `-arch arm64 -o MyApp -s <slide> -f <symbol file>`. However, it prints lines like `type metadata accessor for GradientView (in MyApp) (<compiler-generated>:0)`. I'd like it to print the mangled name instead, e.g. `_$s22FeatureImpl12LanguageCellC19GradientViewSo012GradientI0CvpACTk`. I need this for various reasons, including to pass to an order file for the linker. Is there any way to do this with `atos`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround without `atos`. I can use the private CoreSymbolication framework directly:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <mach/machine.h>
#include <mach-o/arch.h>
#include <architecture/byte_order.h>

struct sCSTypeRef {
    void* csCppData;    // typically retrieved using CSCppSymbol...::data(csData & 0xFFFFFFF8)
    void* csCppObj;        // a pointer to the actual CSCppObject
};
typedef struct sCSTypeRef CSTypeRef;

typedef CSTypeRef CSSymbolicatorRef;
typedef CSTypeRef CSSourceInfoRef;
typedef CSTypeRef CSSymbolOwnerRef;
typedef CSTypeRef CSSectionRef;
typedef CSTypeRef CSSegmentRef;
typedef CSTypeRef CSSymbolRef;
typedef CSTypeRef CSRegionRef;
typedef CSTypeRef CSUUIDRef;

CSSymbolicatorRef CSSymbolicatorCreateWithURLAndArchitecture(CFURLRef url, cpu_type_t type);
CSSymbolRef CSSymbolicatorGetSymbolWithAddressAtTime(CSSymbolicatorRef cs, vm_address_t addr, uint64_t time);
const char* CSSymbolGetMangledName(CSSymbolRef sym);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, CFSTR("/path/to/dSYM/binary"), kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
    CSSymbolicatorRef cs = CSSymbolicatorCreateWithURLAndArchitecture(url, 16777228 /* arm64 cputype */);
    int slide = ...;
    ptrdiff_t addr = ...;
    CSSymbolRef sym = CSSymbolicatorGetSymbolWithAddressAtTime(cs, addr - slide, 0);
    const char *name = CSSymbolGetMangledName(sym);
    printf("%s\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

https://github.com/mountainstorm/CoreSymbolication/blob/master/CoreSymbolication/CoreSymbolication.h provided the prototypes